# Como inserir um DataRow no meio de um DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, inserir

Preciso dar um InsertAt de um DataRow no meio de um DataTable, mas da maneira que estou fazendo sempre da erro "Esta linha já pertence a outra tabela"

```
DataTable subpedido = Pedido_FichaTecnicaDAO.PegarInstancia().ConsultarPedidoID(Convert.ToInt32(this.gridPedidos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value));
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)gridPedidos.DataSource;
for (int i = 0; i <= subpedido.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    DataRow row = subpedido.Rows[i];
    dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, e.RowIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: Talvez por conta da referência, acho que você precisar criar uma new row e fazer o "de para" das colunas e seus valores.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? talvez com um cast também funcione